# Installer fails with "failed to load installer component" with ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

Using QEMU, I have this failure:

[image: Fail]

I checked the CD image's integrity, checked the md5sum, everything is fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to happen if your VM isn't given enough RAM. I gave it 256MB and it happened everytime. If I changed it to 768MB then it doesn't happen... I guess this is that.

I'm leaving it here anyway because I couldn't find anything when Googling for this issue.

Comment: This was also my problem. I was installing Ubuntu's minimal ISO (50+ MB) on Proxmox. It never occurred to me that this tiny ISO would need more than 256MB of memory. +1

Comment: Thank you so much! This was my issue as well, and similar surprise to @Gene.

Comment: @springloaded I have given it like 8192 mb memory but it still its the same